# Why the angular form validation works partially?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms

My code is resided [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr6yrj).

The web page will popup a modal when the button is pressed.

The problem that:

1. Select an item in "division"
2. Select an item in "System" drop down box.
3. it should show "form.valid=true"
4. Clear the "division" input box, then "System" drop down box is clear.
5. Although the error message is shown "Division Name is required", 
   the message "form.valid=true" still be shown.

I expect the message "form.valid=false" is shown, however, it show the message "form.valid=true".
How can I solve the problem?

.

Comment: There is no validator set on the app-division-list-input-box component (which is a form control component), so it can't possibly be invalid (even though the matInput that the form control component uses internally is invalid). In short, the `required` attribute should be set on app-division-list-input-box, not on its internal matInput.

Comment: In your 4th point, you say that clearing the "division" input box is also clearing your dropdown box. But in fact it isn't, if you clear your division input in one way not letter by letter you will see that system input is still written. You need to find a way to really clear your system input when your division input is clear.
Hope I was clear on this explanation

Answer (score 0):

Although JB Nizet's remark is very accurate, I think there is one more step towards your solution.

When using `ControlValueAccessor`, you provide a way for your component(`app-division-list-input-box`) to communicate with the Forms API.

For this reason, you **don't** want to have the **required** attribute **only** on the input, which resides inside `app-division-list-input-box`'s view. That's because the `input` is just a DOM element, but it does not **directly** communicate with its parent form container.
As a result, you should define the `required` validator on `app-division-list-input-box` in order to define the **required validator**.

#### manual-contact-editor.component.html

```html
<app-division-list-input-box
    name="division"
    [(ngModel)]="this.callTreeManualContactMapping.division"
    required
    [divisionList]="this.divisionList">
  </app-division-list-input-box>
```

But, this will not suffice.

Because, when you change the `input`'s content, `app-division-list-input-box`  does not inform its parent form container.

You'll have to invoke `onChange` whenever the user types something inside the input:

#### division-list-input-box.component.html

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Division</mat-label>
    <input 
        matInput 
        type="text" 
        [(ngModel)]="division" 
        (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
        [matAutocomplete]="divisions"
        name="division2" 
        [divisionValidator]="this.divisionList" 
        (ngModelChange)="autoCompleteFilter($event)"
        #division2="ngModel"
    >
    <!-- ... -->
</mat-form-field>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2zwws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2FA%2Fmanual-contact-editor%2Fmanual-contact-editor.component.html).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Why I need to define 1 more  (ngModelChange) handler? I have tried the append  "this.onChange(evt);" into the end of autoCompleteFilter($event) method, but it still does not work.

Comment: @HKKNVB add `<pre>{{ manualContactEditForm.value | json }}</pre>` in your template, and you'll see that even when you delete the last character in the division, it doesn't properly inform the form that the value is now empty. Instead, it keeps the last character.

Comment: @JB I also found this situation, but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, you only call `this.onChange(evt);` in the else clause, when the evt is not falsy. You need to call it whatever the value is.

Comment: @HKKNVB, is not the provided StackBlitz demo a solution to your problem? It seemed to work fine

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hohgt5?file=src/app/modules/utility/components/division-list-input-box/division-list-input-box.component.ts

Comment: @HKKNVB did I miss anything here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2zwws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2FA%2Fmanual-contact-editor%2Fmanual-contact-editor.component.html

Comment: I have fork the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hohgt5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Futility%2Fcomponents%2Fdivision-list-input-box%2Fdivision-list-input-box.component.ts

Comment: @HKKNVB, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6xtuj?file=src/app/modules/utility/components/division-list-input-box/division-list-input-box.component.html

Comment: After the "Division" is changed, if I don't select any system name from the drop down list , then the "System" required validator not working now